# powershell write 0xC3BF (UTF-8) instead 0xff

Tags: powershell

This is my code on PowerShell

```
$buffer = New-Object byte[] 256
$buffer[0] = 0xff -as [byte]
```

I try to set `$buffer[0]` to 0xff. but it write 0xC3BF (UTF-8) instead 0xff

How to fix it?

Comment: `$buffer[0] = 0xff` works just fine - something on the _receiving_ end is interpreting your _byte_ array as (the low byte of) UTF-16 code units to be encoded as UTF-8-encoded _text_.

Answer (score 2):

0xC3BF is correct as it is the UTF-8 representation of 0xff.
If you want to see the hex output you can use [Format-Hex](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/format-hex?view=powershell-7.1)

Use as follows:

```
Format-Hex -InputObject $buffer
```

Output:

```
           00 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 0A 0B 0C 0D 0E 0F

00000000   FF 00 00 00
```

Answer (score 0):

yes. if show hex its 0xff. but if i send data throw socket

```
 $Socket = New-Object System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient( $_host, $_port)
 
 $stream = $Socket.GetStream()
 
 $writer = New-Object System.IO.StreamWriter($stream)
 
 $writer.WriteAsync($buffer, 0, 1)
 $writer.Flush()
```

it send 0xC3BF instead 0xff

Answer (score 0):

if i use

```
$writer = New-Object System.IO.StreamWriter($stream, [System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII)
```

it send 0x3f (?) instead 0xff